# Why the JS keyboard code for ^ returns dead?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm doing a simple JS script which takes all the keyboard events and shows them on screen. Every time I try the symbol <kbd>^</kbd> (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>) on my keyboard JS returns a dead code.

Why is that happening and how can I solve it?

```
editor.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var keyNum = event.which || event.keyCode;
    
    switch(keyNum) {
    case 9:
        buffer += "\t";
        break;
    case 13:
        buffer += "\n";
        break;
    default:
        if (window.event) { // IE
            key = e.key;
        } else if (e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
            key = e.which;
        } 
        buffer += key;
        break;
    }
    
    renderText(buffer);
});
```

Comment: Share some code to help out

Comment: If I make your `editor` as an `input` tag, I can see every key press. Typing a `caret` (`Shift` + `6` = `^` on a US keyboard) works fine, and detects both the `Shift` and `^`. Perhaps I'm not able to reproduce the problem because I don't have an AltGr key?

Answer (score 5):

This is expected because this key is a special type of modifier:

The name comes from mechanical typewriters, where a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) refers to a key that doesn't move the paper carriage but waits for the next key stroke to apply its effect.

In most software contexts now when you press this key it is somehow highlighted to indicate that it's not a complete character in itself.

[image: dead key highlighted]

(Although the character ^ exists, but you still have to press a second key like space to move the caret)

The question is: what should browsers do when this key is pressed?

If we look at the [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) interface, it provides two useful properties to know more about a key press, the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) properties.

The `code` property refers to the physical key bound to the layout of the keyboard. There is no problem detecting which physical key is pressed and in my case pressing ^ returns `BracketLeft`. Again this is layout dependent: for example in an AZERTY layout pressing A gives a `KeyQ` code.

The `key` property refers to the printable representation of the key. This where the problem is, since a dead key typically is not a complete character as the system is waiting for the next key stroke. So it doesn't have a printable representation (yet). As the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) says:

> If the KeyboardEvent represents the press of a dead key, the key value must be "Dead".

So you will observe the same behavior with other accents ¨ ` etc. which all return a `key` property with value `Dead`.

And as opposed to other modifiers like `AltGr` or `⌥ Option` which are pressed and held while pressing another key, a dead key is pressed and released before the key it should modify. You can detect the former ones with the `altKey` and `metaKey` properties of the KeyboardEvent, but you cannot detect the ^ modifier since it's a dead key and not a complete character.

Answer (score -1):

The keyboard events [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) and [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) are both deprecated and have been for many years. You should use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) which is the modern way to determine exactly what key value was pressed across all keyboards and languages.

```js
addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
});
```

From the link above

> If the KeyboardEvent represents the press of a dead key, the key value must be "Dead".

Comment: But you still can't determine that the alt grave was pressed until another key is pressed? You can only know that a dead key was pressed?

Answer (score -2):

It's fine on eg US or UK keyboard as you type {Shift}6 to get ^ and it just works.

In other languages you have to type something different eg for German keyboard Just the ^/° (key at top-left) which gives

```
e.key = "Dead"
e.code = "Backquote"
e.keyCode = 220
```

so interpreting "Dead" seems difficult without just special-casing (and maybe guessing which language keyboard your user has)